# which file integration service pickup and which file will be used as parameter file?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica

i have a file 'A' and File 'B' which has business date as a variable both files have different values.I specify file A in session level and file B is specified in workflow level in path.So which file integration service pickup and which file will be used as parameter file?

Answer (score 0):

At session level file 'A' will be used as it will override the workflow level parameter file. For all other session's in which file A is not specified as parameter file 'B' will be used as it is specified at workflow level.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to the concept of local and global variables in a way.

Workflow level parameter file will be your global level, and Session level param file will be your local variable.

Thus whenever a session has is defined with a parameter file it will use the same parameter file **(in this case A)**.

If you have sessions that do not have any parameter file defined then those sessions will use **B parameter file** defined in the workflow level.